# elastic stack twitter sample tweets

Tags: elasticsearch, twitter, twitter-oauth, elastic-stack

I am new to elastic stack and not sure how to approach the problem. I have managed to get live stream of tweets with specific keyword using Twitter input plugin for elastic however I want to get a sample real time tweets with no specific keyword, just a percentage of all real time tweets. I tried to search how to do it but cannot find a good documentation, I believe I need to use the GET  statuses/sample API but there is no documentation on it. This is what I have for now:

```
input {
  twitter {
      consumer_key => " cosumer_key"
      consumer_secret => "consumer_secret"
      oauth_token => "token"
      oauth_token_secret => "secret"
      keywords => ["something"]
      languages => ["en"]
      full_tweet => true
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {}
}
```

How would I search for all sample tweets without using the keyword?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you just want some results of what you've  already indexed? GET twitter/_search

Comment: right now the tweets im getting are all including the keyword "something", what i want is a dataset of random sample tweets in real time, without any specific keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example random score query, this should solve your problem:

```
GET /twitter/_search
{
"query": {
"function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
        "random_score": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Edit - Adding a logstash config that takes random entries as well:

```
input {
  twitter {
      consumer_key => " cosumer_key"
      consumer_secret => "consumer_secret"
      oauth_token => "token"
      oauth_token_secret => "secret"
      keywords => ["something"]
      languages => ["en"]
      full_tweet => true,
      use_samples => true
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {}
}
```

[use_samples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-twitter.html#plugins-inputs-twitter-use_samples):

> Returns a small random sample of all public statuses. The tweets returned by the default access level are the same, so if two different clients connect to this endpoint, they will see the same tweets. If set to true, the keywords, follows, locations, and languages options will be ignored. Default ⇒ false

Comment: do I need to change my twitter.conf file (for logstash) that I have attached above? or do I just add this query to elasticsearch somehow? Im sorry if its a silly question, I am very new to this and I find it hard to find clear documentation on how to do it. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The logstash configuration and this are completely unrelated. You just need to run this query against your elastic instance that logstash is shipping data to.

The answer I provided is the snippet of code I'm executing in the developer tab of Kibana, but you can do similar things via anything that can make a request to your elastic instance. Take a look at the curl or console examples here for an example of where you would use this request:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

"Postman" is my API tool of choice for elastic without Kibana.

Comment: I have tried the code in kibana console however I am still only getting results with the keyword i set up in configuration file (my keyword is "london"), please see screenshot below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERhTr.png

Comment: I see what you're saying, the logstash config you're using is definitely limiting the scope of what you can ingest. Looking at this documentation, it seems you can't wildcard the keywords, but you can take a sample of all tweets using the "use_samples" option.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-twitter.html#plugins-inputs-twitter-keywords

Comment: I think that works! i have tried it before actually but not in correct way i guess. now im getting tweets in different langueges as well, but im not bother about that. thank you once again https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jbmn.png

Comment: Glad to hear it works, could you upvoate/accept if this worked for you? Thanks!